# How to add items at the end of the list in jquery caroufredsel plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm currently developing a slideshow using jQuery Cycle for the slides and CarouFredSel for the thumbnails.

I just want to know how to add items on CarouFredSel dynamically. I want to get the thumbnail images from the server and add the results to the existing set of thumbnails on the CarouFredSel.

I have already read the documentation from their website but I'm so confused. The result is not what I had wanted. Maybe I can say I did not understand all the documentation about adding the items.

Can someone give me an explanation on how to add items on CarouFredSel? I want the thumbnails images to be added always at the end of the item

For example

1 2 3 4 5 6 7

If there are three new items, I want those items to be added after "7" so the new list set would be

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Then so on so forth. Then I will add 3 again and then the new list set would be

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13

Comment: it has something to do with jQuery "append", but it would be much more helpful if you could post the code that you already have, if you're using "ul" or "ol" as holder, just $( "#id_of_the_unordered_list" ).append( "<li>text | element</li>" );